# Access issue with Azure Synapse studio

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I created a Synapse workspace in my Azure Portal and tried opening the Synapse studio and I received the following error:

> Failed to load one or more resources due to No access, error code 403.

```
credential    
linkedService      
dataset   
pipeline   
trigger  
sqlscript
notebook
sparkjobdefinition 
dataflow
```

What could be the reason. I believe I have required access to resource groups

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had this issue and I was able to solve it by doing the following:

1. Open Synapse Studio from Overview screen in Synapse
2. Click Manage from the left navigation blade
3. Click on Access Control in Security
4. Click Add and then Select the Role "Synapse Administrator"
5. Select the User permission should be given to
6. Select Apply

After that, log out and log back to Azure and the error should disappear.

In case you still see the error then you need to access to the Synapse workspace and under the Security tab you need to click on it and add the range of IP addresses that will have access to the instance.

Comment: Log out/in is important. A simple refresh does not work.

Answer (score 4):

This could be an intermittent issue while opening synapse workspace.

Could you please confirm the permission on the Synapse workspace which you are trying to login?

[image]

Make sure you have required permissions to access workspace:

- From Azure Portal under Synapse Workspace, user needs to have Owner/Contributor permission
- From Azure Portal under Synapse Workspace, user needs to enable correct IP address under firewall settings

**Option1:** Try to manually login by going to the `https://web.azuresynapse.net` and sign into your workspace.

[image]

For more information, refer to the [Open Synapse Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/get-started-create-workspace#open-synapse-studio)

**Option2:** You please try the below:

1. Clear “Cookies and Cached data” of your browser.
2. Private Mode (New InPrivate Window).
3. Try in different browser.

Answer (score 3):

Go to your storage account -> Access Control (IAM) -> Role Assigments and check if you can find ther role storage-blob-data-contributor if not add it.

This role shoulde be added automaticly but there are exceptions fron this rule

Detials are here [how-to-grant-workspace-managed-identity-permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/security/how-to-grant-workspace-managed-identity-permissions)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix the same issue by following these steps:
Open "Azure Synapse Studio" with your admin account from the Workspace,
Open Manage\Access Control\ and add the user you need with Role Synapse Administrator or more adequate privilege.
Sign Out "Azure Synapse Studio"
Sign In with the other user that you just gave privilege to.

Answer (score 1):

We also experienced the same error message but it was caused by improper configuration of private endpoints. If you are using private endpoints, you need four of them: one for the Azure Synapse Private Link Hub and three for the workspace sub-resources (SQL, SqlOnDemand, and Dev).

Once we corrected the issue this error went away for us and Studio behaves normally now.

So as the other answers point out, this can be caused by missing RBAC roles or by networking issues.

Answer (score 0):

As per abautista this was the fix for me:
Synapse Studio >> Manage >> Access Control in Security >> Add yourself as the Role "Synapse Administrator"